# Objective C completion block doesn't get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, completionhandler, completion-block

I am trying to call a completion block in a unit test but it never reaches.
Here is the code:

```
[vc configureRecorder:^{
    NSLog(@"Completion...");
}];
```

This is the method:

```
-(void)configureRecorder:(void(^)(void))callback {
    NSLog(@"Method");
}
```

Comment: I assume you did call `callback()` somewhere inside of @"method"? If you didn't then why do you expect it to be called. If you did - how? Mind that unit tests executed on main  thread, and do not waiting for anything asynchronous to happened in another threads. If it is a case - take a look on XCTestExpectation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1500899-expectation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the completion block at the end of your method. like this:

```
-(void)configureRecorder:(void(^)(void))callback {
    //@"Method"
    callback()
}
```